# Let $f: [a,b] \to R$ be continuous almost everywhere. Can we find a $g:[a,b] \to R$ such that $g=f a.e.$ and that $g$ is left continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function that is continuous almost everywhere w.r.t. Lebesgue measure. Can we find a function $g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g=f$ almost everywhere on $[a,b]$ and that $g$ is left continuous?

I think this is true. Is this a well-established result?

Comment: Where does the problem come from? Why do you think that it is true?

Comment: It's in a problem set by a professor. I'm taking his module this semester. I am in fact asked to "prove or disapprove by counterexample" the above statement. I working on a proof myself at this moment, not sure whether it is really true.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for your comment. If I am not wrong, the $f$ you provide is in fact increasing in $x$, then, $f$ is known to have at most countably many "jump" points. At a jump point $x$, we can replace $f(x)$ with $\lim_{y \to x^{-}}f(y)$, which results in a new function that is left continuous and equals to $f$ almost everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Note $f(x)=sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is continuous on $(0,1]$, however, it can not be continously extended at $0$.

Note if $g$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$ such that $f=g$ almost everywhere on $[0,1]$, then $f=g$ on $(0,1]$ otherwise there will be a small interval where $f\neq g$ since $f,g$ are continuous on $(0,1]$. Hence, $g$ is a continuous extension of $f$, which is not possible, otherwise $f$ will converges at $0$

Comment: The question does not ask for a continuous $g$. In fact, there are multiple errors in this answer.

Comment: Despite some flaws in this example, it does inspire me. Consider $f$ on $[0,1]$ where $f(x)=sin(\frac{1}{1-x})$ for $x<1$, and f(1)=c for some c. Suppose that there is a $g$ as required, then, we can have that, for some $\epsilon>0$, $|g(y)-g(1)|<1/4$ for all $y\in (1-\epsilon,1)$. However, we can always find a interval $I \subset (1-\epsilon,1)$ and $f(I) \subset [-1, 1]\backslash [g(1)-1/4, g(1)+1/4]$. As a result, $f \neq g$ on $I$, which is contradicting to that $f=g$ almost everywhere.